# unable to double the volume of audio

Tags: javascript

I want to play only the audio of a mp4 video file. So far I'm here and this function works fine without any errors:

```js
function MovieAudio() {

    const video = document.createElement('video');
    document.body.appendChild(video);
    video.id = 'clip'; 
    const clip = document.getElementById("clip");
    clip.style.visibility = "hidden";
    const source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = 'myvideo.mp4';
    source.type = 'video/mp4';
    video.appendChild(source);
    video.load();    
    clip.volume = 1;
    clip.play();

} // end of MovieAudio function
```

The problem is I want to double the volume of the audio and if I set the volume like this I get an error:

```
clip.volume = 2;
```

I find a solution here but I can't make the code work...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794379/10715551

```
// create an audio context and hook up the video element as the source
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(clip);

// create a gain node
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 2; // double the volume
source.connect(gainNode);

// connect the gain node to an output destination
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

How can I double the volume of audio with the given code?

Comment: Have you tried changing `myVideoElement` to `video` in `createMediaElementSource`?

Comment: _"I get an error"_.  Go on...  What was the error message?

Comment: we can not set a volume more than [0-1] range... if we do that it produces an error..

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (2) is outside the range [0, 1].